# Is there a solution for composer to run composer install with this situation?

Tags: composer-php

I have a Magento 2.3.1, I pulled new modules from using composer to my /var/_swap as been suggested due to ram/composer merging issue.A nd then I move the module's vendor file to my application root, upgraded my Magento .and now I need to do "composer install" and update my composer.json & validate lock's metadata for my previous add on .but I stumble across this issue and not able to proceed.

nano into composer.json and change to dev in minimum stability
--no-plugins

```
  Problem 1
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 requires magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-metapackage[1.1.1].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 requires magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-metapackage[1.1.1].
    - magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.1 requires magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-installer[1.1.0].
    - magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.1 requires magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-installer[1.1.0].
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.1].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
```

I would like to install module and validate it ,so i know it is working on my application

Comment: What version of composer are you using?

Comment: composer version 1.0.0-beta2

Comment: That version is over 3 years old. Try updating composer with `composer self-update` (if your version supports it) or fetching the newest version from https://getcomposer.org/download`

Comment: composer self update doesnt work .i manually wget and installed it,but how do replace my old ver of composer?